# How to run piped code line by line in R (dplyr)?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Is there any add-in that allows to run piped code line by line in R without altering the code?

For example, I would press keys at each line and it would print the output in the console.

```r
# AS AN EXAMPLE
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl2 = 2 * cyl) %>% 
  filter(cyl2 > 15)
```

I am aware of the `ViewPipeSteps` add-in but it's not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I use `dplyr` and `data.table` daily, and I've never seen a tool that would do that. I don't think it's impossible, I'd think one could parse the expression, split by `%>%` (or `|>`), and iteratively evaluate the steps. But I have never come across it nor know how to implement it well/elegantly. (I tend to just select portions and evaluated highlighted-code as I step through it.)

Comment: See the suggestions here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/whats-currently-the-recommended-way-to-debug-pipe-chains/14724/2

Comment: For a specific use case—presenting lines iteratively in a slideshow—I've used the [`flipbookr`](https://github.com/EvaMaeRey/flipbookr) package. It's very cool but I've found it a little buggy & hard to work with.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify what you're looking for here: you want step through the pipe line by line and see each successive output **without** altering the code at all (e.g. with commenting as suggested)? Fundamentally, I don't see how you can get the code to behave differently without changing it and it sounds like that's what you're asking for.

Comment: @DanAdams I will add this clarification

Comment: The [nakedpipe](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/nakedpipe) package seems to have a few features that might suit your need.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to debug would be to define the following function, which prints out intermediate steps in the pipe while otherwise continuing the calculation:

```r
`%>>%` <- function(a, b) {
  a <- match.call()$a
  b <- match.call()$b
  print(eval(a))
  eval(substitute(a %>% b))
}
```

For example, if I wanted to debug the following pipe at the second pipe operator:

```r
mtcars <- mtcars[1:5,]

res <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl2 = 2 * cyl) %>% 
  filter(cyl2 > 15)
```

I could replace the `%>%` with `%>>%` to find out what the state of the calculation was at that step:

```r
res <- mtcars %>% 
   mutate(cyl2 = 2 * cyl) %>>% 
   filter(cyl2 > 15)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb cyl2
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   12
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   12
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    8
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1   12
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   16
```

But the correct final calculation is still stored in `res`

```r
res
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb cyl2
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2   16
```

I'm not sure how useful this would be in practice. Typically if debugging a pipe I would comment out the pipe operator at the end of the line then run the code to see where I'm at, then delete the `#` and move to the next line. I guess there may be cases where that's inconvenient, but I don't recall seeing any.

Comment: Not convenient enough to explore someone else code.

Comment: @julien yes, it's a downside of the pipe. It sounds like what you are looking for would be a feature request in RStudio?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I have seen an add-in that does this job

Answer (score 0):

I usually just highlight the relevant lines in my script and execute manually (`ctrl` + `enter` in Rstudio).

You mentioned going to each line and pressing keys to inspect output up to that point, so what I often do if debugging a long pipe is add `.[]` (or sometimes `head()` depending on the object type and what I want to see from it) at the end to just return whatever happened before and then comment out lines I want to remove (which can easily be done with `ctrl`+`shift`+`c` in Rstudio - those are your keypresses). Then I un-comment lines one-by-one as I debug. Finally remove the last line and final `%>%` once you're satisified.

E.g. I might run these in succession.

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  slice_head(n = 5) %>% 
  # mutate(cyl2 = 2 * cyl) %>%
  # filter(cyl2 > 15) %>%
  .[]
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
  
mtcars %>% 
  slice_head(n = 5) %>% 
  mutate(cyl2 = 2 * cyl) %>%
  # filter(cyl2 > 15) %>%
  .[]
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb cyl2
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   12
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   12
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    8
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1   12
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2   16

mtcars %>% 
  slice_head(n = 5) %>% 
  mutate(cyl2 = 2 * cyl) %>%
  filter(cyl2 > 15) %>%
  .[]
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb cyl2
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.02  0  0    3    2   16
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Not a convenient solution